# Is it possible autoload PHP classes in themes?

Tags: 8, theming

Does the namespace, class name and naming convention work like it does for modules?

These links don't seem to mention it:

- https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/standards/psr-4-namespaces-and-autoloading-in-drupal-8
- https://www.drupal.org/node/2349803

Comment: I believe it should but looking at bootstrap they seem to be needing a fix https://git.drupalcode.org/project/bootstrap/blob/8.x-3.x/autoload-fix.php

Comment: It's not available by default, and from a logical standpoint, usually shoudln't be necessary, as the theme layer is for theming things.

Comment: Thanks @giorgosk ! It appears to work OOTB, using composer drupal-project install. Autoload fix be might needed though for batch and ajax callbacks though as noted in bootstrap theme.

Feel free to add answer.

Comment: This depends on what you want to load, you can't use plugins or container services for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should but looking at bootstrap they seem to be needing a fix 
https://git.drupalcode.org/project/bootstrap/blob/8.x-3.x/autoload-fix.php

Answer (score 5):

There's an interesting development going on regarding themes and OOP. Look at [Allow themes to provide services.yml](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2002606) which finally got closed as Won't Fix. From Mark Carver's closing [comment](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2002606#comment-12609849):

> I really don't think we should be opening up themes to services
>   anymore.
>
> A lot has changed (for the better) in the 5 years I've been following
>   this issue (closely).
>
> If this were to happen... there wouldn't be any real delineation
>   between what a module is vs. what theme is, would there?

Instead as a result [Allow themes to declare dependencies on modules](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/474684) is the route to go now. To move all the OOP stuff out of themes as *the theme layer is for theming things*, as JayPan said in the comments.

My answer to that problem is that I now always create a `themename_companion` module where I provide Drush 9 commands, helper functions, services etc. for my themes.